# is currentUser logged in different device

Tags: ios, parse-platform

This is a simple question, is there **a Parse** format for checking if the user is already logged in, in a different device?

I'm aware I can manually do this, updating objects, registering devices and using pointers etc etc, just wondering if there is a simple API workaround or an easier alternative someone has creatively utilized?

Comment: You could set up a couple fields to handle this. When the user logs in on a device, you could set a field in the user table with the UUID of the installation object, and a second field to show the user is logged in, either with a 1 or text like logged in. Then with a logout button you could remove the flag for being logged in and the UUID. May not be 100% fool proof such as in the event the user gets logged out without hitting the button.

Comment: That's the solution I'm trying to avoid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is. They announced [sessions](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#sessions/iOS) in the latest Facebook conference. You need a basic find or count query in `Session` class:

```
var query = PFSession.query()!
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{ (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    if error != nil {
        println(error!)
    } else {
        if let sessions = objects {
            println(sessions)
        }
    } 
}
```

Note that you don't need to add `query.whereKey("user", equalTo: currentUser)`. Because the query will only return the sessions of the current user due to the ACL set on the session object. The session object is something like:

```
createdWith =     {
    action = signup;
    authProvider = anonymous;
};
expiresAt = "2016-04-14 13:43:53 +0000";
installationId = "...";
restricted = 0;
sessionToken = "...";
user = "<PFUser: 0x7fc990681120, objectId: yoELURj4i8>";
```

Comment: Well done. Thanks. I have been bad about reading their changelogs lately. I haven't tried this answer yet, but i think the fundamentals of it is the direction I'm looking for. It doesn't have cloud code triggers though..not sure if thats good or bad. I'll test this out and offer an obj c equivalent for future question seekers

Comment: You're welcome. I tested this code piece. Was working as expected. Hope it works for you too.